# Edit duplicate closure target after close vote has been cast

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

Sometimes a question is clarified ( *rarely* ) after a duplicate closure, and the clarification is still a duplicate just of a different question.

A more common case is sometimes you copy paste the wrong URL or find better duplicate afterwards or someone that can't vote to close points out a better target when closing as a duplicate and need to change the target.

Right now, if you remove the duplicate closure you lose your ability to vote to close on the question again for the new ( *or better* ) duplicate target.

At some kind of least grace period like on editing comments would even be acceptable, because people are pretty quick to complain about duplicate closures.

**We need a way change the duplicate target question without reopening the question to answers.**

Comment: For every close voter or limited to Dupe hammers?

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: I don't fancy 5 close voters all change their dupe vote. That is likely not going to happen. But in the limited area with trusted users I see no problem giving you that option. So your FR can be implemented then in steps.

Comment: Whilst I can see its appeal to recent/active questions. I wonder if it would get abused by users that would want to change dupe targets of older questions to questions they have asked or have an accepted answer to.

Comment: so put a TTL on it just like editing comments, and anyone can change a dupe target of something they have not voted to close to something else now, that is not a problem today. everything *can* be abused. I can reopen any [tag:java] question with a single click and dupe hammer it to whatever I want if it is the first time now. This is about changing the target after it has already been voted on.

Comment: Since the question was edited, it's in the review queue.  Does retargeting it cancel the review?

Comment: On the rare occasion that this happens to me, I just take it to the relevant chat room and ask if someone's willing to re-hammer.  They usually are.

Comment: @sayse I don't expect it to be abused but you can expect that dupe voters  choose a target they know. This [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/514450/dupe-voting-to-either-your-own-question-or-a-question-with-your-answer) shows the number of questions used as a dupe target where one of the close voters is an OP on the Q/A target. You'll find our most trusted users in that list which show their effort.

Comment: @rene: Wow, that's an interesting query!

Answer (score 9):

As of today, you **can** change the duplicate link on a duplicate-closed question - [*if* you have a gold badge for one of the tags on the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links).