# Add duplicate modal does not get focus and does not accept Enter

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, design, user-interface

Gold tag badge holders [can edit the list of duplicate targets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328249/edit-duplicate-closure-target-after-close-vote-has-been-cast) of a question that is closed as duplicate by clicking the "edit" link:

[image: edit duplicate list]

When you click that link, you navigate to the "edit originals" page, where you can add another duplicate target:

[image: add duplicate target]

However, the modal window that appears after clicking Add, doesn't function exactly like the initial window when closing the question in the first place.

Firstly, the textbox where you can enter a link, search term or question ID doesn't get the focus when it's shown:

[image: textbox without focus]

Secondly, when you do put the focus on that element and paste or enter a value and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the preview of the question loads (and reloads on every successive <kbd>Enter</kbd> press), but the chosen question isn't selected: you have to explicitly click the "Add Original" button.

[image: the button that doesn't trigger on Enter]

In my opinion, those two issues are bugs, because they differ in functionality from the default duplicate modal window.

Comment: This is a great annoyance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed:

- entryfield will get focus immediately when the dialog is displayed
- enter keypress when a question is selected will close the dialog and add the selected question to the list

This *should* behave identically to the close-as-duplicate dialog now; lemme know if something still seems off.

Comment: This is now broken in the reverse: [the normal close vote dialog is no longer submittable with enter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398876/1048572), but the edit duplicates one is.

Comment: That's... Unfortunate, @bergi. Donno how the react button is stealing focus, but hopefully that test comes to a merciful end soon and resolves the issue.