# Should I use my dupehammer to open an XY problem?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

[This is the relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46738588/sort-by-elements-of-a-list-of-tuples)

The original title and post body asked how to swap tuples in a two-element list. The example the OQA showed was simply reversing the list, and that was the quick response of many a pythonista, including close votes to the canonical [How can I reverse a list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python). I asked a couple follow up questions that revealed that what he really wanted was not to reverse the list, but had to do with sorting.

By that point the question had already been voted a dupe by four users and hammered closed. I used my hammer to re-open since it wasn't a dupe of the targeted question, and answered for the benefit of OQA.

...However, it *is* still most definitely a dupe (possibly of [Sort a list of tuples by 2nd item (integer value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695139/sort-a-list-of-tuples-by-2nd-item-integer-value)), and most definitely is a low-quality question. Would it have been better to leave this closed and possibly comment the answer for OQA instead?

Comment: If OP messed up asking the proper question and the older question has been dealt with (answered or closed as dupe), then they need to ask a new one (afair).

Comment: Related: [What should I do when the OP asks the wrong question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322991)

Comment: @torazaburo I guess the question comes up because the incorrect dupe target was *correct* before OP figured out what he was supposed to be asking. It feels akin to editing the question when it invalidates current answers.

Comment: @AdamSmith I'm curious why you decided to answer it even though you knew it was a duplicate of another question? You could have re-closed it as a duplicate of the question you did find, even without knowing about editing the duplicate list. Further.. you admit yourself that it's most definitely a low quality question. Answering low quality questions sends the message that these types of questions are suitable for the site, especially when it comes from an established user like yourself.

Comment: @Rob I don't agree with SO's general philosophy that we should be gatekeepers of knowledge and only cough up useful information if new users can formulate a proper question. Though I see its utility on a macro level (we're all volunteers here, and projecting an "Ivory Tower" appearance is helpful to keep rank beginners from taking up volunteer time), I reserve the right to help a user personally if I feel they need it and I have the time to spend. This question is more about the moderation after the fact, than whether or not I should have answered at all.

Comment: @Rob see also one of my two [answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257949/room-owners-should-be-allowed-to-accept-20-rep-users-to-talk-in-a-room/258060#258060) here on Meta.

Answer (score 27):

The only time I'd reopen a duped question is if it's *clear* that the dupe doesn't answer the question.  Since you yourself said:

> ...However, it is still most definitely a dupe

...reopening it was **not** appropriate.  You can just edit the target dupes to be something else as opposed to point to the one that's wrong now.

Comment: You can edit target dupes? How do you do that?

Comment: There's an edit button below the title of the dupe on the right hand side.

Comment: @AdamSmith: It's *relatively* new.

Comment: Re-opening and re-closing would definitely have been appropriate as well. Even only re-opening a question with the wrong target (and leaving further review to others) would have been fine. What's wrong is to post an answer to a question that is known to be a duplicate.

Comment: @Bergi:  As we've previously established, it's a wasted cycle to reopen the question.  You can just edit the target dupe list instead.

Comment: @Makoto I don't see anything wasted there, I guess opening+closing even is faster than editing [due to the sub-par usability of the edit dialogue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349364/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi:  Besides forever losing a reopen vote on the question...I suppose you're right.