# Duplicate selection dialog glitches

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, close-dialog

While I was trying to add a second duplicate link to a closed question, I clicked on the one I wanted to select and *while it was still loading*, I accidentally hit the <kbd>< back to similar questions</kbd> link and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUYot.png) happened:

[image: Screenshot]

Both the selected question and the default suggestions showed up beneath each other. Ooops.

Comment: Eh, its less detrimental than when I go to YouTube, click a video, then click back quickly. I end up on wherever I was, but with a video playing that I can't see or stop.

Comment: Also, is that ~7 million results?!

Comment: @Nisarg: Looks like all the questions with answers on SO.

Comment: While this question has attention, I'd like to readdress my question about that very same dialog: [Add duplicate modal does not get focus and does not accept Enter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349364/add-duplicate-modal-does-not-get-focus-and-does-not-accept-enter) which I reported a year ago.

Comment: @Nisarg When you search and then clear the input, it ends up with *all* questions as the result

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this in the way you describe it. But I have been able to get it by typing a slow search term and then clicking on an item in the list before the search completes.

Comment: @Shog9 That might have been the case, I'm not completely sure what exactly I clicked accidentally. In any case there's a data race, by looking at the code one should be able to figure out what could lead to the resulting screen.