# Duplicate modal doesn't accept Enter after pasting link

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions

Find a random question you believe to be a duplicate. Find an original question that solves the problem and copy the link. Click "close", then "Duplicate". Modal opens. Paste link from clipboard. Press Enter.

**Expectation**: the Enter is interpreted as a click to "Vote to close".

**Actual behavior**: the modal stays open and refreshes its contents, in addition to "Thanks"ing the accepted answer (and sometimes that causes an error)*:

[image: You can't react to your own post]

*: Yes, I'm suggesting an original question that I happen to have asked.

Related, but fixed: [Add duplicate modal does not get focus and does not accept Enter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349364/add-duplicate-modal-does-not-get-focus-and-does-not-accept-enter)

Comment: Looks a lot like [Multiple flag dialogs for posts can be opened with the keyboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349919/multiple-flag-dialogs-for-posts-can-be-opened-with-the-keyboard)

Comment: @Scratte similar, but this involves explicitly giving focus to something within the dialog

Comment: @Nick If I recall correctly the bug in my link was first noticed the same way as posted here. It then turned out it was much more than that.

Comment: @Scratte yeah it looks like a focus problem, the flag one also applies to my Chrome browser. I don't know the error message shown here though, how does one "react" to a post? Make a video about it?

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm not sure what your "how does one "react" to a post?"-question means, but the "You can't react to your own post" looks like the same as when one tries to [Thank](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction)-react to one own Answer.

Comment: Doesn't look like this is happening any more now that the Thanks "feature" has been removed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is resolved since [the "thanks" reaction is currently disabled](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398909/data-validation-background-for-the-thank-you-reaction-feature-test).

Additionally, a code fix is in review should the feature be turned on again and to address a similar issue on Stack Overflow for Teams.

Basically, the issue is that the reaction button was implemented as `<button>...</button>` which is functionally equivalent to `<button type="submit">...</button>` when contained within a form.

When the question loaded and you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the browser looked for the first submit button within the form and sent it a click event.  That button was unfortunately the react button on the first answer.

The fix was to explicitly annotate these as `<button type="button">...</button>`.

Reactions that correspond to subsequent duplicate votes pointing to the answer's question will be appropriately accounted for when analyzing the experiment.

Answer (score 22):

What's even much, much worse: Instead of casting a close vote on the current question with the selected question as the duplicate target, it does [cast a *Thank you* reaction-vote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398367/1048572) on the accepted answer of the selected question. I've accidentally reacted to about a dozen answers now even though I did not want to take part in the feature test. This also does sometimes cause an error message (which can be seen in your screenshot) when the accepted answer is your own, in which case you're not allowed to react to it.

(Also [reported on the announcement post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399133/1048572))

Comment: I see in my "votes and reactions" activity that this is indeed the case.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm going to undo these now. At least they're not locked in.

Comment: Ah, mystery solved! I was *wondering* how that "thanks" reaction snuck into my profile history, as I definitely didn't use that feature intentionally.