# How to duplicate the question back after retracted once?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Mistakenly I duplicated the OP's question with wrong duplicate. So what I did is, I retracted my duplicate and tried once again to duplicate with correct duplicate once but it didn't allowed me to do that ? 
[image]

My question is how can I close the OP question with valid duplicate after retraced so that it can help OP ?

Comment: Just leave a comment and hope somebody will VTC it instead......

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344878

Comment: Post a [cv-pls](https://socvr.org/faq#how-and-why-do-i-need-to-format-my-cv-pls-and-other-requests) in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) if you provide the correct duplicate target as well.